# Trying try/catch for the first time - php

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I have done a lot of PHP coding but never used `try/catch` before. First time user. It won't work, does not even compile. I am trying this very simple example.

```php
$x = 0;
try {
    if ($x == 0) {
        throw new Exception('x is zero');
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $ex->getMessage();
}
echo 'after try block';
```

When I run this, I get this error message referring to the line with the catch in it.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ex' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'
```

Was expecting to get the Caught exception line displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you copied this from the PHP manual. The manual doesn't use real spaces in their code. That has tricked me up several times already. See:

https://3v4l.org/TW2Zr

Here the fake spaces are shown:

---

[image]

---

You need to make sure you're using real spaces.

In some editors you can make these fake spaces visible, and some other editors will already replace them for you.

Comment: This was the problem. I loaded the code in notepad and specifically made sure that everything that should be a space was a space (although I thought I originally coded it manually anyway). But now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'Caught exception: ', $ex->getMessage();
```

instead of comma, there should be a full stop for string concatenation

```
echo 'Caught exception: '. $ex->getMessage();
```

Comment: Comma is fine, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.examples

Comment: Thanks for that didn't know about it.